# How do I transfer my locked ERC20 tokens from an old account to a new account?

Tags: ether, myetherwallet

I want to move my ERC-20 to another wallet. I can't find a proper documentation that helps explain how can I do this. I am using [myetherwallet.com](http://myetherwallet.com) and they have contract tab and I haved tried the transfer instruction mentioned in this [link](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/11484/how-can-contract-ownership-be-transferred-from-one-account-to-another) on the myetherwallet but no luck. Can anyone tell me what am I doing wrong?

Comment: You didn't say what is wrong, so until you add more info we can't help you there. But if you want to transfer ERC20 token from an address to another, you can use MyEtherWallet (choose Send Ether & Tokens, import your source key, and it will let you choose Ether or Tokens and a destination address).

Comment: I want to move my ether to another wallet because my old wallet was hacked. I have tokens which are not on the exchange yet, so I have been in contact with some of the companies that start token sales and they told me I have to wait for it to go public so then I can move them. But my question was more about how can I use the [link](https://www.myetherwallet.com/#contracts) page to move the ownership of my contract to my new wallet, or transfer contract because in the dropdown we do have functions with those titles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm trying to abstract how to think about ERC20 Tokens on the Etherum network.

If you think of your normal Ethereum Account as a safe-deposit-box, and your 
private key as the physical key for that safe-deposit box, the ERC tokens you 
own are not really inside your safe-deposit box.

They are inside another safe-deposit-box (the ERC20 Token contract, each token have their own).
Inside that safe-deposit box is a ledger/list that specify how much of that ERC20 Token each account holds.
To send tokens from your account, you must sign a message with your key, proving you are the owner of the account.

Sometimes the ERC20 Safe-deposit-box is locked (tokens are not transferable yet) and you must then wait for the 
box to be unlocked by the ERC20 Token contract owner before any token transactions can be instantiated.

Does this make sense?

Answer (score 2):

From your comment, you have recently participated in a crowdsale (many of which have been phishing targets). Also, the tokens you have purchased are currently locked in the ERC20 token contract and these tokens will be unlocked shortly by the crowdsale administrators.

While the tokens are locked by the token contract, you will be unable to move them. The phisher is also unable to move them. Immediately after the tokens are unlocked, you can then use MyEtherWallet to transfer your tokens to your new account.

You may want to contact the team conducting the crowdsale, and try to arrange a time when they notify you that your tokens are unlocked so you can immediately transfer your tokens to your new account, before the phisher has the opportunity to do so.

You are not trying to change the ownership of the token contract. All you need to do is to transfer your token balance from your old account to your new account.

Following is MyEtherWallet's guide to [Sending & Adding Tokens](https://myetherwallet.groovehq.com/knowledge_base/topics/how-do-i-send-tokens-and-add-custom-tokens).