# We have a contract on OpenSea that has a Metamask wallet as the owner, we would like to change that to a Gnosis Safe Wallet, Can We?

Tags: gnosis-safe

We would like so funds cannot be moved without all owners signing off on this but as we currently see it. The funds would need to be manually moved to the gnosis safe by the wallet owner first in order to secure the funds. Can we remove the manual piece of the process?

Answer (score 0):

The contract owner can't be changed unless you implemented a function to do so within the contract. See here: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/11492/92183